# Subclassing a subclassed LinearLayout class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, subclass

I've a class `PinnedListView` which subclasses `LinearLayout`. I've got another class `NonDiarisedPinnedListView`which subclasses `PinnedListView`.

About 90% of the functionality is the same, just the layout and a few extra bits on the `NonDiarisedPinnedListView`.

But when I load it up, the layout of the `PinnedListView` is loaded as opposed to my `NonDiarisedPinnedListView`. Any particular reason why and is there I can get round it? Here's the relevant code:

`PinnedListView` constructor:

```
public PinnedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.pinned_list_view, this);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final ImageView arrowButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrowButton);
    arrowButton.setSelected(true);

    final RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
    header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!arrowButton.isSelected()) {
                arrowButton
                        .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float);
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                arrowButton.setSelected(true);

            } else {
                arrowButton
                        .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                arrowButton.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

`NonDiarisedPinnedListView` constructor:

```
    public NonDiarisedPinnedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.non_diarised_pinned_list_view, this);
}
```

As you can see, the latter is empty besides the new layout. It's taken out something (That's not referenced in the former's constructor) and it's got a few things added which are used in other places.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the super that you are calling. I would suggest overloading the constructor of the `PinnedListView` class and allowing it to take a layout `int`.  See the below example

```
public PinnedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(R.layout.pinned_list_view);
    }

    public PinnedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int layout) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(layout, this);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final ImageView arrowButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrowButton);
        arrowButton.setSelected(true);

        final RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
        header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!arrowButton.isSelected()) {
                    arrowButton
                            .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float);
                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    arrowButton.setSelected(true);

                } else {
                    arrowButton
                            .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    arrowButton.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public NonDiarisedPinnedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.layout.non_diarised_pinned_list_view);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I suspected it was the super constructor, but I thought it'd just overwrite anything mentioned afterwards.That seems like a decent approach to solving it. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm, mate. I was just checking it worked. To be honest, it clicked when I saw what you wrote,so I knew it would work anyway, but you never know! Thanks a lot!